# Can changing default Shell by using "sudo" make unexpected problems later?

Tags: linux, shell, default, sudo

I'm a new user of Linux. I installed ZSH and made it my default Shell according to the guide on its GitHub but I used Sudo by mistake. Is it OK? or do I need to undo what I've done and just change it with user permission?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just made it the default shell for root. It won't cause you any issues if that is what you did.

```
# set default shell for a non-root user:

$ sudo --user <USER> chsh -s /bin/zsh
```